# Selecting element by id from jQuery collection

Tags: jquery

How to select an element by id from a jquery collection?

e.g.

```
var jQObj = $("div");
```

How to access a div with id say `div_1_1`  from the collection `jQObj?`

Thanks

Comment: -1 for far too basic question.. answer is `var jQObj = $("#div_1_1"");` by the way.

Comment: :) I don think that's my question. 
Since i have the collection of divs in a variable (jQObj), i don't want to query the DOM again to get the particular element by id. This is already part of the collection, how do i access from it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, @TimothyGroote: I guess you both are off here. The question is not how to query within the DOM, but to select a node from a jQuery collection.

Comment: OK, didn't understand this from first read. @jAndy already gave correct and full answer in this case.

Comment: OK, didn't understand this from first read. @jAndy already gave correct and full answer in this case.

Comment: i figured that out, but too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the structure within `jQQbj`.
If `#div_1_1` is on the "top level" you need to invoke `.filter()`:

```
var $myDiv = jQQj.filter('#div_1_1');
```

wheres if `div_1_1` is somewhere as childnode invoke `.find()`:

```
var $myDiv = jQQj.find('#div_1_1');
```

Reference: [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/),  [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#div_1_1", jQObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = $('div');
var myDiv = divs.filter('#singleDiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to filter it in that way? Is that block of code in the middle of a mad jQuery chain you don't want to break?

Just curious because ID selectors are fast (especially compared to running your collection through $.fn.filter) so I don't quite get the aversion to re-querying the DOM.

I put up a quick [jsperf test here](http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-requery).

Comment: In that case definitely ID selector would be a better option, the decision to filter was solely to minimize re-querying and the performance overheads.